# ASP .Net Razor: Render ViewBag item and replace char

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm having issue, what I want to do is:

I'm getting user e-mail address from my controller as ViewBag.Email variable.

I want to make label which will have id named 'token' + user-Email replaced char '@' to '_'

(i.e. e-mail is abc@abc.com, I want to have label as id: 'tokenabc_abc.com')

```
<label id="@Html.Raw("token" + ViewBag.Email.replace("@", "_"))">
    @ViewBag.Tokens
</label>
```

I've tried with this code but I'm having problem.

Error:

```
An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException'          
occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'replace'
```

Comment: What problem? And it would be far better if you generate the 'formatted' text in the controller and pass it to the view.

Comment: What problem do you have? What id do you get when you do it like this?

Comment: I've edited my question with error code. By the way I've succeeded following Stephen's suggestion to generate field in controller and now it is ok.

Comment: Capital `R` `.Replace()`

Comment: I'm not that sure but functions normaly start with an uppercase. ViewBag.Email.replace( -> ViewBag.Email.Replace(

Comment: Yeah, it was problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem was in capital R in writing method replace -> Replace.**

```
<label id="@Html.Raw("token" + ViewBag.Email.Replace("@", "_"))">
    @ViewBag.Tokens
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write "Replace" and you get working variant. This is code working

```
<label id="@Html.Raw("token" + ViewBag.Email.Replace("@", "_"))">
@ViewBag.Tokens
```